# Unity 3D: after installing and dirty deinstalling plugin (odin), metadata files keeps being added

Tags: unity-game-engine

Good day,

Recently, I have been working on a Unity project. (LTS 2020)
[For it, I imported Odin, a helpful plugin.](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/odin-inspector-and-serializer-89041)

Was cool, but wanted it gone.
That is where the fun ends.

Unity didnt show odin the package manager, so i had to do it in a different way.
After reverting all changes through git and deleting the downloaded file from the \AppData\Roaming\Unity\Asset Store-5.x, I thought that would be it.

No, every time I select the Unity Editor, strange metadata files get added.
Switching to another git branches dosnt help either.

[changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOx7i.png)

What is the reason behind this and how do I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

revert all changes in the git repository
delete all files in \AppData\Roaming\Unity\Asset Store-5.x

switch branch
revert changes through IDE

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer and the reason.

The problem is, that my IDE ignores the files in Assets/Plugins, but not the metadata files generated for it.

Deleting the files, Unity had no reason to create metadata anymore.